# Tools for developer in openSUSE

Tags: linux, virtualbox, eclipse, opensuse, netbeans

I was lately installed openSUSE Tumbleweed on Virtualbox and it works quite well. It find drivers automatically. Previous I used Gentoo however it takes time to compile new and updating packages.

I wanted to install Eclipse or Netbeans and after that I was quite disappointed. Why such big distribution, advertised by sentence: "The makers' choice for sysadmins, developers and desktop users." does not have most popular developer IDEs?

What is standard way to install such tools on openSUSE? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The most standard way of installing anything on any linux OS is by either downloading ready made packages (such as .deb), double click and install

OR

using the terminal to do the job. This would generally require us to fetch the file to our system in our preferred directory (such as Home (`cd ~`)). After that, we would unpack the file if necessary, make it executable (with `chmod`) and finally execute it.

[Here's](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/opensuse/install-netbeans-ide-7-1-on-opensuse-12-1.html) an example.